# Using VPN with Docker

Tags: vpn, docker, ipsec

I use [Laradock](https://laradock.io/) for my project, which attacks an external MySql server. Recently, this server had been protected by Fortinet IPsec VPN. I work with Ubuntu 20.04, so I installed strongSwan as explained in [this article](https://community.fortinet.com/t5/FortiGate/Technical-Tip-IPsec-connection-between-FortiGate-and-Ubuntu-via/ta-p/207149).

After doing `sudo ipsec up MYSERVER`, I can access from console to the MySql server.

However, from docker I get:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59984553/1039488), I tried to add to my docker-compose.yml the following entry:

```
  extra_hosts:
    - "VPN_IP:192.168.150.74"
```

But I still get the same error; docker cannot connect to DB server.

(instead of `VPN_IP` I put the explicit IP, 192.168.150.74 is my local IP which is related to the VPN).

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: It seems that your docker network can't find a route to the VPN network. You can try to manually add a route (route add ...).

Comment: @Vinicius, can you please add more information? I guess I should add something to `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: I think it's not a problem with the containers. Usually containers have a default route the bridge interface on the host machine it self. So all unknown destination should be routed to the docker host machine. A `traceroute` from the docker container to the mysql server would be interesting. Or a `tcpdump` on the bridge interface also could be helpful.

Comment: try to use `host` networking and see if this solves your problem

https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode

Comment: it seems you need to enable forwarding in sysctl

Comment: Also, extra_hosts is a directive that adds an entry to the /etc/hosts file in the container, it doesn't help at all with networking, it only helps to avoid issues with domain name resolution within containers.